# Is it possible to query AD from a machine that is not attached to the domain?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I am writing a small c# app to run at startup when a new machine is booted, connected to our corporate network.

I have some code which checks whether a machine account for the machine already exists on the domain, and if so deletes it, prior to joining the machine to the domain.

This works fine on my computer, which already has the trust set up to the domain, but doesn't from a test machine which is not yet joined.

Is there a way round this? Not sure if this is one for Serverfault or Stackoverflow - so hedging my bets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, via LDAP, as long as you can connect to a domain controller via your underlying network transports (ie- TCP/IP).  You'll need to bind to Active Directory under the context of a domain user who has at least read access to the directory.  You'll also need to specifically call out which domain controller you want to connect to as autodiscovery relies on a domain connection.